# Breadboard layout with speaker

Tags: arduino, breadboard, speakers

This project is from Arduino's Examples page. The first fritz is from there. I managed to run that example without any issues. However, I had tried keeping the wires together so I tried to run the project with a breadboard but have had no success. What is wrong with the second fritz?

1.

[image: Original Fritz from Arduion.cc]

2.

[image: My Fritz]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the breadboard doesn't work like you think it does.

Inside the breadboard are strips of metal.  In that breadboard they run vertically linking groups of 5 holes together:

```
O   O   O   O   O   O
|   |   |   |   |   |
O   O   O   O   O   O
|   |   |   |   |   |
O   O   O   O   O   O
|   |   |   |   |   |
O   O   O   O   O   O
|   |   |   |   |   |
O   O   O   O   O   O
```

Your wires are in different metal strips to the legs of your resistor, so they are not connected to anything.

Move the wires into the same columns as the resistor legs and it will work.

You can see on the Fritzing drawing that when you place a component on a breadboard the holes above and below it are highlighted in green.  These are the holes that are connected internally by the metal strips.

Comment: (thanks!) 'the' to 'they' 3rd sentence. 'Edit' won't let me change something so small.